# DetailView + input button

Tags: python, django, button, view, detailview

I would like to add a button to "validate" a user towards the next step of his registration.

The staff member have to "validate" the user in the user detail page.

So I created a DetailView view with template with all the details of this user.
But I would like to know if it is possible to write code in DetailView function to allow the user to increment his step_registration variable when I click on "validate" ?

Here is my DetailView function :

**views.py**

```
class StudentDetailView(DetailView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Student
    login_url = login
```

**student_detail.html**

```
{% block content %}
  <h1>Etudiant: {{ student.user.firstname }} {{ student.user.firstname }}</h1>
  <ul>
    {% if student.photo %}
      <li> Photo :<img src="{{ student.photo.url }}", width = 250, height = 300>"> </li>
    {% endif %}
    <li> Etat de l'inscription : {{ student.step_registration }}</li>
    <li> Date de naissance : {{ student.birthdate }} </li>

  </ul>
<button class="btn btn-secondary"> Validate ! </button>

{% endblock %}
```

The step registration variable is called "step_registration", so I want to do student.step_registration += 1 when a staff member click on "validate"

Comment: this is something about dynamic forms, please read this [article](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2018/05/07/creating-dynamic-forms-django/), if it helps... I've done the same thing but with VueJs on the front-end

Comment: if you want to do it the "classic" way, just create a `validate_user` view for stuff only and increase the step there and save the student..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the button only visible for staff members (you can also add logic to show it only at certain steps):

```
{% if user.is_staff %}
<button class="btn btn-secondary" href="/validate_student/student.id"> Validate ! </button>
{% endif %}
```

add the view and link it in urls.py (you maybe add some logic/checks or set the step to a certain value):

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
def validate_student(request, id):
  student = Student.objects.get(id)
  student.registration_step += 1
  student.save()
  return ... # redirect or success page
```